# Falls off network ("Destination host unreachable")

Tags: raspbian, networking, python

I am running my Raspberry Pi headlessly, connecting via SSH over the network. I am having a problem that I can consistently reproduce. I will leave a Python script running on my Raspberry Pi and come back a few hours later and SSH connections to the  Raspberry Pi will time out.

If I ping it I get the following:

```
C:\Users\andrew>ping 192.168.1.42

Pinging 192.168.1.42 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.46: Destination host unreachable.
```

The only way I can get it back on the network is to restart it (pull out the power).

Has anyone experienced this? Are there any log files I can look at to diagnose the issue?

Comment: On a raspberry, I have only a cronjob running a python script, and it too will die after a few hours up to 2 days. I cannot SSH it anymore, only a restart by cutting power will help.

Comment: @k0pernikus interesting! I am trying now running it with with the scren attached, so far (4 hours and counting) and it hasn't failed. Are you using screen at all?

Comment: what's in your /etc/network/interfaces? Anything scary in `dmesg`? How is RPI connected to the network? Via a router? What's in the router's logs? If you re-plug the ethernet cable to RPI, will it bring it back to the network?

Comment: @abolotnov I'm actually finding this now if I run the RPI with a monitor attached - it seems to take longer, but when I come back after 6 or so hours it will be unresponsive. dmesg seems clear.

Answer (score 9):

The wireless device goes to sleep after a period of no activity. It's a powersaving scheme.

You need to turn off the powersave feature of wlan0.

I'm using an edimax wireless usb receiver:

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 7392:7811 Edimax Technology Co., Ltd EW-7811Un 802.11n Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8188CUS]
```

It uses the 8192cu module in the kernel.

To turn off powersave, add the following to /etc/modules, or create a file (8192cu.conf) in /etc/modprobe.d/ with the line(s):

```
# prevent power down of wireless when idle
options 8192cu rtw_power_mgnt=0 rtw_enusbss=0
```

Next reboot (or rmmod/insmod) it should disable the sleepy mode and your pi will be accessible all the time.

I create the file for /etc/modprobe.d and it's part of a script I built to do preliminary setup on a new build.

Comment: This was on a wired network

Comment: Unfortunately, I have the same problem with these features turned off. Wireless adapter still gets turned off after a number of hours of inaction.

Comment: I am curious as to whether they're actually turned off.  The modprobe.d files much be named particularly (x.conf) and spelling counts (as always).  Is your wireless adapter a 8192cu unit? perhaps you need a different module?

Comment: @lornix: What command did you use to print out the type of wireless receiver you are using?

Comment: `lsusb` and `lsusb -v` are very helpful.  Figuring out which module isn't always easy, There are ways to match up output of `modinfo 8192cu` to the vendor:product numbers in `lsusb` output.

Comment: I added above line to /etc/modules, right after snd-bcm2835 (which was the only existing entry). Result when booting up was "[info] loading kernel module options" next line "FATAL: Module options not found"

Comment: Following on from my previous comment: it does work, however, on the /etc/modprobe.d/8192cu.conf file !! It is worthy to note that BEFORE i created this file, iwconfig reported Power Management:off (which was incorrect!)

Answer (score 2):

It is common for a router to disconnect inactive clients to free up router resources.  This can happen at random times if the client has not been active.

Answer (score 2):

The problem for me was power management on the wifi as well, but I was not using a 8192cu chipset, so the instructions in the other answer didn't work for me.

Run `iwconfig` and look for the line that starts with `power management`

If it says that power management is on, you can turn it off with:

`iwconfig wlan0 power off`

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that extensively `ping`-ing does bring up the wifi-connection again in my case. I observed that after the 70-100th ping the *Pi* starts responding and after that a `ssh`-connection can be initiated successfully.

**Edit** Turn power save off

```
iw wlan0 set power_save off
```

Click here for [details](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/97864/22174).

Answer (score 0):

Earlier Raspberry Pis had issues with the wireless power management. Other answers have covered this. The power management can be turned off (until reboot) with `iwconfig wlan0 power off` or `iw wlan0 set power_save off` to check whether this helps.

Old Raspberry Pis that use ifupdown configure the `wlan0` interface in `/etc/network/interfaces`. In those machines the setting can be made permanent by
adding `wireless-power off` under the `wlan0` definition. In newer machines you may be able to disable it by configuring the kernel module in `/etc/modprobe.d/`. Note that there are several different Realtek wireless drivers that your system may use: 8192cu, rtl8192cu, rtl8xxxu. You can alternatively type `crontab -e` and add the following line, making the command to be called at reboot:

```
@reboot sudo iw wlan0 set power_save off
```

Raspberry Pi 4 shouldn't have the same problem with power management, but there's another issue with dhcpcd that recent Pis use for configuring network interfaces. If you can connect a keyboard and a monitor, check whether dhcpcd is running (`systemctl status dhcpcd`). It may happend that dhcpcd is killed wtih SIGSEGV when running Docker containers that define virtual networks. In this case you should see the following message when you type `grep dhcpcd /var/log/daemon.log`:

```
systemd[1]: dhcpcd.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=11/SEGV
```

The solution is to disable dhcpcd for virtual networks. Add the following line to `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`:

```
denyinterfaces veth*
```