# Wake up 'sleeping' wlan-connection

Tags: networking, wifi, wireless

I observed, that after a while (some hours) my *Pi* isn't reachable over the wlan any more. If I do some excessive `ping`-ing (i.e. for 70-100 times) the *Pi* starts at some point to respond and I can successfully establish an `ssh`-connection.

Q1. Can somebody explain why the above approach works?

Q2. What can I do to keep the *Pi* connected?

**EDIT 1**

- *distribution*: Raspbian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy), Linux version 3.12.28+
- *wifi-dongle*: Edimax Technology Co., Ltd EW-7811Un
- */etc/interfaces*:

  ```
  allow-hotplug wlan0
  auto wlan0
  iface wlan0 inet manual
  wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
  iface default inet dhcp
  ```
- the *Pi* has a static IP

**EDIT 2**

Today, I received a wifi-dongle from the [The Pi Hut](http://thepihut.com/products/usb-wifi-adapter-for-the-raspberry-pi) which does not suffer from the aforementioned problem up to now. `ping` and `ssh` work immediately.

**related posts** [1st](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/5098/falls-off-network-destination-host-unreachable/24176#24176), [2nd](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/19457/ssh-into-raspberry-pi-times-out-ping-cant-reach-host/24150#24150)

Comment: You can install something like `wicd-curses` but you must ditch suplicant. When you configure your wifi there is an option to autmotically connect. Each wifi you tick this on, wicd will try to connect to those wifi until connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the advice from [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/34952/22174) I did

```
$ iw wlan0 get power_save
Power save: on
```

It was ON, and I set it to OFF with

```
iw wlan0 set power_save off
```

*Hint* To make this setting permanent I did [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/96644/22174).

Comment: Also there are some differences between `iw wlan0 get power_save` (which works perfectly) and `iwconfig` (which might display wrong data about the real powermanagement status). Some USB-Antennas also got this problem.  
 I had to update the driver `sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/8192cu.conf` and add the line `options 8192cu rtw_power_mgnt=0 rtw_enusbss=0`. This line will prevent the powermanagement from shuttign down usb and wifi

Answer (score 5):

These problems often seem to be related to wireless power management.

As a first attempt try

```
iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

Comment: I've just checked it: power-management is off.

Comment: @participant In that case I suggest you edit your opening post and give details of the wireless dongle you are using, the distribution you are using, and anything else which might help localise the problem.

Answer (score 2):

A crude way of keeping the connection alive: on the Raspberry Pi, create a crontab entry (`crontab -e`) to ping a host once an hour:-

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
  3 *  *   *   *     ping -c 1 somedomain.com > /dev/null
```

Comment: I've seen scripts like that around here, but I would prefer a configuration which takes care of that issue.

Comment: I realise it's not ideal, but it might tide you over until you find a 'correct' solution, and it's not exactly a resource hog.

Comment: Nice workaround. I would replace somedomain.com by the ip address of own router to make it less "interfering".