# “Destination Host Unreachable” when not logged in

Tags: networking, pi-3, ubuntu, ping

I `ping` a device on my network by its local IP. When the device is logged out (at **lock screen**), I get a wall of "Destination Host Unreachable". When the device is logged in, the pings return just fine. Remote is 16.04 Ubuntu MATE on a Raspberry Pi 3, via Wi-Fi. I originally thought I was having a `ssh` issue with home encryption, but I realized it's a general networking issue.

I could use your help determining whether this is a hardware or software setting issue.

Answer (score 3):

Did some digging and this is likely a **wireless power save** issue.

```
$ iw wlan0 get power_save
Power save: on
```

For more, see [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/34794/968). I've since moved to a wired connection, which is stabler and doesn't have this boot/greeter issue. Hope you can benefit from my blind efforts