# Make "iw wlan0 set power_save off" permanent

Tags: wifi, power-management, systemd-startup

**Q** How can I make `iw wlan0 set power_save off` permanent for stretch? What's the proper way to do it?

**Edit** I'm using an r-Pi 1 Mod. B with an Edimax wifi dongle and Raspian stretch.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Power save mode was an issue years ago on older versions of Raspbian. But it is fixed for a long time. Now it is disabled by default with the WiFi  driver **brcmfmac**. You will find it if you grep the journal for the driver:

```
rpi ~$ journalctl | grep brcmfmac:
Apr 14 22:13:28 raspberrypi kernel: brcmfmac: F1 signature read @0x18000000=0x15264345
Apr 14 22:13:28 raspberrypi kernel: brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_map_chip_to_name: using brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio.bin for chip 0x004345(17221) rev 0x000006
Apr 14 22:13:28 raspberrypi kernel: brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware version = wl0: Feb 27 2018 03:15:32 version 7.45.154 (r684107 CY) FWID 01-4fbe0b04
Apr 14 22:13:28 raspberrypi kernel: brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: CLM version = API: 12.2 Data: 9.10.105 Compiler: 1.29.4 ClmImport: 1.36.3 Creation: 2018-03-09 18:56:28
Apr 17 09:01:27 raspberrypi kernel: brcmfmac: power management disabled
```

As you see, it is `power management disabled`. So there is no need to worry about it. You don't need to disable it again.

**Update** after getting information about used hardware:
If you do not have an on-board WiFi and using an USB/WiFi dongle then you will not find `brcmfmac` because there is another driver loaded for the dongle. To execute programs on boot up you can use a **systemd** Unit file. I will give you here a bit more comfortable example for switching off or on power_save. Create a Unit file with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl --full --force edit wifi_powersave@.service
```

In the empty editor insert these statements, save them and quit the editor:

```
[Unit]
Description=Set WiFi power save %i
After=sys-subsystem-net-devices-wlan0.device

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/sbin/iw dev wlan0 set power_save %i

[Install]
WantedBy=sys-subsystem-net-devices-wlan0.device
```

Now enable just what you want on boot up:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl disable wifi_powersave@off.service
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl enable wifi_powersave@on.service
# or
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl disable wifi_powersave@on.service
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl enable wifi_powersave@off.service
```

Comment: `journalctl | grep brcmfmac` doesn't report anything, but `iw wlan0 get power_save` reports `Power save: on`. I'm using a Edimax Wifi dongle.

Comment: @participant It is an important information. You should have said it in your question. On a Raspberry Pi with on-board WiFi **wlan0** is used for it and **wlan1** for additional USB/WiFi dongle. So what version of Raspberry Pi do you use? Please edit your question and complete it.

Comment: @participant I have updated my answer.

Comment: Isn't `rpi ~$ sudo systemctl enable|disable wifi_powersave@off.service` sufficient, because the default behavior is power save on?

Comment: @participant Yes, it's only nice to have to switch off and on, maybe for testing. Maybe the Edimax wifi dongle supports power save? If you only want one service then replace `%i` with `off` and `sudo systemctl enable wifi_powersave.service`.

Comment: Awesome systemd magic. I modified this on my system be `@$WLANDEV` instead of `@STATE` _(`/sbin/iw dev %i set power_save off`)_ just in case there are multiple Wifi devices.

Comment: " Now it is disabled by default with the WiFi driver brcmfmac" - Not the case on my Raspberry 4 with default settings. It says "power save enabled".

Comment: Oh and your systemd service does not work the way you describe it, as systemctl cannot find the service. Therefore I created a standard service the usual way.

Comment: "Now it is disabled by default with the WiFi driver brcmfmac" seems to be OS version related. Power Management is enabled on my Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2 using Raspberry Pi OS Lite released 2021-03-04. Like @PhilippLudwig I created a standard service.

Comment: @PeterGloor As far as I know the Foundation changed the default setting from `powersave disabled` on operating system **Raspbian** to `powersave enabled` on the **Raspberry Pi OS**.

Comment: I'm using a Raspi Zero W with onboard wifi, but for a retropie. It seems the **retropie's latest Raspi Zero** image comes with powersave enabled - I remember having set if off the first time I sat with it, but now when I came to mess with it the second time, all the ssh suffering started again. `brcmfmac` shows `power save enabled` on the journalctl - we must remember that Raspi isn't just the hardware, it depends on which flavor people are using ;) So while that could be truth for latest (or other versions of) **Raspberry Pi OS**, it may not be for others.

Answer (score 26):

I did it by simply adding a line to /etc/rc.local

`/sbin/iwconfig wlan0 power off`

Add that ahead of
`exit 0`

and it will run at every boot.

Comment: haha googling for the subject I found your post on the official forums! This one worked, and I thank you and upvote you!

Comment: A smart one :-)

Answer (score 4):

This is still relevant for me when I want to use the RPi headless and log in through SSH, as there are no input devices plugged in and power management kicks in too early. Sometimes I couldn't log in via SSH, because the interface was already down. To permanently turn off WiFi power management, edit "/etc/network/interfaces" and add:

```
allow-hotplug wlan0
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
wireless-power off

# For second WiFi device, e.g. via USB
#allow-hotplug wlan1
#    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
#wireless-power off
```

Comment: This works! Only thing that did on a 3A+ with 64bit raspberry pi os.

Comment: I had upvoted, but this one failed me =( this setting makes no difference for the Raspi Zero W running retropie... I restarted the device, `cat` the file, the configuration was still there... but I was back on having trouble until I `sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off` it.