# Pi Zero W as a WiFi Access Point - WiFi Dropping Out every minute or so

Tags: wifi, pi-zero-w, access-point

I have setup a Pi Zero v 1.1 & Camera with latest Raspian Buster Lite to replace an old Drone Camera which has failed. I have it running as a router using [this url](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point-routed.md) and streaming the video fine from [here](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes2.html#web-streaming).
The problem is the WiFi keeps cutting out every 30 - 60 secs and staying off for 30 to 120 secs.
By a lot of searching I discovered that the WiFi Power Saving was enabled by using this command:

```
sudo journalctl | grep brcmfmac
```

gave this result:

```
brcmf_cfg80211_set_power_mgmt: power save enabled
```

So more searching I found [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/96606/make-iw-wlan0-set-power-save-off-permanent) from this forum as a way to disable the Power saving which works as shown by issuing the command:

```
sudo systemctl enable wifi_powersave@off.service
```

and then the command above to show the result on a reboot:

```
brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware: BCM43430/1 wl0: Oct 22 2019 01:59:28 version 7.45.98.94 (r723000 CY) FWID 01-3b33decd
brcmfmac: brcmf_cfg80211_set_power_mgmt: power save enabled
brcmf_cfg80211_set_power_mgmt: power save disabled
```

It would seem that the Power Saving has been disabled, but this has made no difference to the behavior. The WiFi is still cutting out.

I would be delighted to overcome this and save buying a new drone!

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Am I correct in inferring that your issue is the WiFi connection and the fact there is a camera for use in a drone is extra information about context of the application (but there are no issues with that side of things)? To help us provide a useful answer, what are the minimum set of steps you would follow (from fresh image) in order to observe this issue whereby the WiFi drops out?

Comment: My question is - How can I stop the WiFi dropping out despite having disabled the Power Saving.

Comment: The Camera side of things works perfectly. 
There is no WiFi interference (nearest house is a good kilometer away) I have two access points one on channel 3 another on channel 11. I have set the Pi at channel 7.
I have a WiFi scanner on my phone. I can see the Pi come up on channel 7 for up to a couple of minutes then drop out for 30secs to 2 mins and so on. When the WiFi is up I can connect fine and see the streaming video.
So why is the WiFi dropping out despite being disabled

Comment: Powersaving mode isn't an issue anymore since years, no matter if it is off or on. Don't waste your time with it.